# How do I install tkinter for blender 2.8 in Windows 10?

Tags: python

I get this error:

```
>>> import tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
 File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.80\python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
  import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

I tried to install it but it didn't work:

```
c:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.80\python\bin> python -m pip install tkinter
Collecting tkinter
 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tkinter (from versions: none)
 ERROR: No matching distribution found for tkinter
```

Comment: I don't have the solution to this. Tkinter isn't listed in pip, it is installed or not while instlaling python. However, why do you need to use tkinter, when you have the GUI of bpy?

Comment: I'm just more familiar with tkinter.  The better solution would be to learn the bpy GUI.